# Какие есть игровые движки для Scheme/Racket?

Tags: разработка-игр, lisp, scheme, racket

Для Racket был найден game-engine, но он не настолько допилен и поддержки физики там никакой, для Scheme в виде Guile есть Chekadee, но у него очень мало документации, может есть еще какие движки? Не предлагайте пересаживаться на Common Lisp или подобное ибо Scheme в разы легче

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- https://github.com/get-bonus/get-bonus/wiki - экспериментальный движок
- https://github.com/samvv/racket-gaming - простой 2d-движок
- https://github.com/icela/FriceEngine-Racket - порт популярного игрового движка
- https://github.com/samvv/ramunk - FFI для физики Chipmunk
- https://github.com/jeapostrophe/mode-lambda - спрайтовый 2d движок
- http://www.nongnu.org/gzochi/  - движок ММО
- http://www.pawfal.org/fluxus/  - лайв-кодинг миров

Answer (score 1):

На самом деле, когда нибудь познакомиться с Common Lisp будет полезно)

https://github.com/lispgames/lispgames.github.io/wiki/Common-Lisp - там есть раздел и про Схему, глядишь чего найдешь для себя.